# Cocos2d Sprite linking

Tags: iphone, ios, linker, cocos2d-iphone, sprite

If this question is a duplicate, plz correct me.
What I want to do is to have a character on the screen who may hold a gun.
So if the background move, the character should move with it.
And if the character move, the gun should move with him/her.

Does anyone know how to do this?
Sorry for being a newbie

Kind regards

Comment: here is my guess: since everything in Cocos2d is node, if character node is a child node of screen node then when the screen move the character moves with it. Am I correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `CCLayer` for what you would like to do.

A `CCLayer` is a sort of "container" for all the sprites you want to control as a group. E.g., you create two `CCSprites` and add them to a CCLayer; you can define the sprites position in coordinates that are relative to the `CCLayer` and when the `CCLayer` moves, the sprites go with it.

You can also have multiple layers, for different groups of objects. E.g., if you have more characters, they could all go into the same layer.

A `CCLayer` is derived from `CCNode`, so you could do pretty much the same by adding your character, its weapon, and the background to the same node; but I would suggest to have a node for the two sprites (character and weapon), and a layer for the background sprite and the character+weapon node.

A `CCLayer`, in comparison to a `CCNode`, adds the possibility of handling the accelerometer (if your want your character follow it) and touches.

Comment: Any CCNode derived class can be used for grouping/layering nodes, CCLayer is but one option. In this particular case it is going to be better to add the gun CCSprite to the character CCSprite, and the character to a layer, node or scene.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D: it seems to me that I have also stated that the OP could decide and use a CCNode instead of a CCSprite; I have outlined what CCLayer offers in addition to CCNode, so that the OP can decide what is best for him. Now, I understand you suggest a different option, but why the down-vote? Furthermore, I would invite you to read carefully this sentence of mine: "but I would suggest to have a node for the two sprites (character and weapon), and a layer for the background sprite and the character+weapon node". Do you really see a big difference from yours?

Comment: @LearnCocos2d: You should read his post more carefully, mate. He deserves to be voted up.

Answer (score 0):

You can instantiate a new `CCNode` and call it's `addChild` method. Usually you would subclass CCNode and call it Character or something. The parent CCNode would contain all the sprite and they would move with it. CCSprite is a subclass of CCNode as well.

```
CCNode *character = [[[CCNode alloc] init] autorelease];
[character addChild:[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"body.png"]];
[character addChild:[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"gun.png"]];
```

Comment: Agree, but it may be even better to add the gun to the body. If the body rotates or scales, the gun stays at the same offset.